# How do you read the original question in Quora?

Tags: quora

I've grown very well accustomed to the simple setup for Q&A on Stack Exchange, and when I Google a question and get a match with a Stack Exchange website, it's great.

However, Quora has grown to be a big enough website that sometimes it's (unfortunately) the only place that I can find a match to my question.

As long as it answers my question, that's great. But I have one huge issue with Quora that drives me crazy:

### How do you read the original question posted on Quora?

The answers to questions often refer to content in the original question, so it seems that there must be some way to see it. However, I can never find anything other than the bold, 7-15 word title at the top.

For example this question:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-MySQL-master-slave-setup

... In the answer, he starts with "No it is not only for backup.".

So where do I find the question that actually mentions something about "backup"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to login to see the details. Question details are in comments.

Previously there was a feature* to add details about your question below the question. Now that feature has removed and question details has been added in the comments.

Login to your Quora account, click on question. Click on comment if there is any. You will see the question details if it have.
[image]

*[Why were question details removed from Quora on August 3, 2017?](https://www.quora.com/Why-were-question-details-removed-from-Quora-on-August-3-2017)